# playing sound without the need to install media player extension

Tags: javascript, media, wav, audio-player

I am trying to embed a sound in an auction website. I want that every time someone's bid, a sound will be played. I tried a simple `<embed>` tag with given ID, and then `sound.play()` through javascript.

The sound is playing, but in IE, a new user is asked to install a media player extension "if he/she trusts the website".

Is there a way to make it play without this message. The following code is in the page:

In the HTML:

```
<embed src="success.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="sound1" 
       enablejavascript="true">
```

In the Javascript:

```
function PlaySound(soundObj) {

  var sound = document.getElementById(soundObj);
  sound.Play();
}
```

And the call to the function:

```
PlaySound("sound1");
```

Comment: Did you think about Flash player?

Comment: no, but can I embed it hidden ? If so do you have a recommended reference for me ?

Comment: Yes, it's posible to hide flash (set width=0 height=0). But playing WAV files can be tricky. Check out example at http://richapps.de/?p=97

Comment: Thank you. Will update on solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're comfortable requiring the user to have Flash, I recommend [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/). It uses Flash in the background but is configured entirely through JavaScript, and it's very customizable.

If you want to do it completely natively in the browser you can use the `<audio>` tag, but you'll find it only works in the very newest browsers, and there are still some cross-browser issues you're going to hit upon. [This Ajaxian article](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/) gives a good overview of how to do it and which browsers support what audio formats.

P.S. A personal opinion, if you don't mind: Don't play background sounds or music without first asking the user. Never autoplay and always give the user the option to stop or mute the sound.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer.

This soundmanager looks promising. I hope it's not too heavy or have conflicts with jquery... 

about the <audio> tag - point is that I need the sound even play in IE6... so I am not sure I want to get in to cross browser issues :(

You right about the auto-play. Thanks

Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: Your concerns are valid. Probably wrapping Flash with JavaScript (as with SoundManager2) is going to be your best bet for backwards compatibility. I don't think SM2 conflicts with jQuery, but it's something you'll have to evaluate. FWIW, the SM2 site says that with gzip enabled the "minified" version is "as light as 6 KB": http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/getstarted/

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution worked great with sound manager 2. Altough the whole installation file is 2.8mb, I think only small part of it actually used.

What I did is put the following code in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

soundManager.url = '<?php echo $root_address; ?>/js/soundmanager/swf/'; 
soundManager.debugMode = false;

soundManager.onload = function() {
  var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
    id: 'aSound',
    url: '<?php echo $root_address; ?>/success.mp3'
  });
}
</script>
```

And replaced the calling to the play sound function with this code:

```
soundManager.play('aSound');
```

I used the simplest API to do it.

Thanks again!