# Playing sound in HTML without installing a plugin

Tags: php, jquery, html

To play the sound I use this code: `<embed src="sound.mp3" hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="false">`. Example: http://www.w3schools.com/media/tryit.asp?filename=trymedia_soundmidiembed

But Mozilla (just tried in Mozilla and it's enough why I want to find a solution) asks for the plugin (QuickTime). So, my question is, can I substitute my code to play the sound without asking people to download certain plugin? Or what should I do?

By the way, it is for live chat, when message arrives I add this code to the body.

Thank you.

Comment: One thing i have to say: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @Neal: yeah, I know that, just found a fast example and that's it.

Comment: The joys of the W3C making media playing available, but not specifying a minimal set of codecs that should be available on all browsers to make it actually possible to kinda-sorta play something without worrying if the client's got the right support for the media you're trying to play.

Comment: i hate web sites that play music with asking me.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `php`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883262/playing-sound-without-the-need-to-install-media-player-extension?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest looking into using HTML5's `<audio>` tag. Here's a good starting point: http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

Code example:

```
<audio src="media.mp3" controls preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>
```

Comment: how can I make it automatically work? And how can I hide it? Because it is for chat actually.

Comment: You can give it an id, and then in css set that id to display:none, afterwards you can call it with javascript like: 

`document.findElementById("myid").play()`

Comment: @good_evening to play it automatically put set autoplay attribute like below <audio src="media.mp3" controls preload="auto" autoplay></audio>

Answer (score 1):

Not a really good solution for today, but maybe tomorrow: **[jsmad](http://jsmad.org/)** "is [a pure javascript MP3 decoder](https://github.com/nddrylliog/jsmad), based on libmad, with an ID3 decoder written from scratch.

For example, jsmad allows Firefox 4.0+ to play MP3s without any Flash. Faster loading times. Fewer security holes. No 64-bit headaches on Linux. Fewer memory leaks."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but there is an old [IE-only html](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tag you can use:

```
<head>
 ⋮
 <bgsound src="sound.mp3"/>
</head>
```